# How would I duplicate a line and change a piece of text inside of the duplicate line?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have recently ran into a problem that I am searching automation for using RegEx using Notepad++. I have some very limited experience with RegEx in N++, however I cannot figure out how to do the following:

I have the following line:

```
["Cost"] = 100,
```

And I want to achieve the following:

```
["Cost"] = 0,
["CostNew"] = 100,
```

Since I have many lines of "Cost" as portrayed above with varying values (I'm just using 100 as an example) I would need an automation for this process.

I am aware that you can create a new line by using "\n", but that is as far as my knowledge extends.

Is there a way of doing this with a RegEx expression? Or is it perhaps done better through multiple RegEx expressions?

Thank you in advance for reading my question!

Comment: If this is a single file, you can do normal search and replace. 1. Search and replace `Cost` with `CostNew`, and 2. Replace `["CostNew` with `["Cost"] = 0,\\n["CostNew` in extended mode. [Replace with newline in notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/42670/replace-r-n-with-newline-in-notepad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with unticked `Match-Case`

Find what: `(\["cos)([^,])`
Replace with: `$1t"] = 0,\n$1$2new`

Comment: Another alternative, with four groups capturing ... find: `(\["cost)("\] = )(10)(0,)`  replace with: `$1$2$4\n$1new$2$3$4`  is quite long ....

Comment: Or with three groups capturing ......  find what: `(\[.*t)(.* )(\d+,)`  Replace with: `$1$20,\n$1New$2$3`